# JQuery click function doesn't trigger unless double clicked first

Tags: html, jquery

I have a div with class `language-switch` in a navigation bar that acts as a button to change the language. I wrote a JQuery code to change the class of the `Main` id and text inside the div, but it can only trigger after the second initial clicks.

I already tried wrapping it in `$(document).ready(function(){}` to no avail.

Confusingly I also have a button to change the theme from light to dark called `mode-switch` and it works the first time without having to be double clicked first.

Here's the html for it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
        <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
          <span class="menu">
            <div class="language-switch">
                <div class="language">EN </div>
                <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="mode-switch">
                <i class="fa fa-sun-o"></i>
            </div>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
```

JavaScript for the `language-switch` button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function changeLanguage(){
        $(".language-switch").click(function(){
        if ($(this).children(".language").text() == "EN") {
            $(this).children(".language").text("ID");
            $("#main").attr("class", "lang-id");
        }
        else {
            $(this).children(".language").text("EN");  
            $("#main").attr("class", "lang-en");      
        }
        console.log($(this).children(".language").text());
        console.log($("#main").attr("class"));
        });   
    });
});
```

and the JavaScript for `mode-switch` button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".mode-switch").click(function(){
      $("i", this).toggleClass("fa-moon-o fa-sun-o");
      $(".light-theme").toggleClass("dark-theme");
      console.log($(this).attr("class"));
    });   
});
```

Comment: not directly related to your problem but you don't have any button in your markup. A div is not a button.

Comment: Not only  `<div>` is not a `<button>`, `<div>` is an invalid child of `<span>`.

Comment: Also, you don't need several DOM ready functions. Only one. Or rather none at all if you placed your `<script>` tags in the proper order right before the closing `</body>` tag, or if you used the Script's `defer` attribute.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I'm new to webdev thing... I'm basically botching up things until it worked, or not in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a function `changeLanguage` which in turn creates an event listener on `$(".language-switch")` elements. It appears the `changeLanguage` function is never actually called in the code provided.

Additionally you have a trailing space in the language node so, initially "EN " != "EN"

Just use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /*$(function changeLanguage(){ -- remove the function*/
        $(".language-switch").click(function(){
        if ($(this).children(".language").text().trim() == "EN") {
            $(this).children(".language").text("ID");
            $("#main").attr("class", "lang-id");
        }
        else {
            $(this).children(".language").text("EN");  
            $("#main").attr("class", "lang-en");      
        }
        console.log($(this).children(".language").text());
        console.log($("#main").attr("class"));
        });   
   /* }); */
});
```

Also consider using `classAdd`. `classRemove` or `classToggle` instead of overriding the class attribute entirely

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".language-switch").click(function(){
        var isEn = $(this).children(".language").text("ID").trim() == "EN";

        $(this).children(".language").text(isEn ? "ID" : "EN");
        $("#main").togglClass("lang-id", isEn)
                  .togglClass("lang-en", !isEn);

        console.log($(this).children(".language").text());
        console.log($("#main").attr("class"));
        });   
});
```

Comment: It's not `classAdd` nor `classRemove ` nor `classToggle`.  it's `*Class` like `addClass` etc.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this (my account is new) but yeah holy cow turns out the issue was because I have a trailing space, removed that and it works like charm now, thank you so much @Jon P